# Tapestry Radio Button Event?

Tags: tapestry

I'd like to do an Ajax/Zone update on a section of my page when a RadioButton which is selected.

```xml
<t:RadioGroup t:id="vehicleAvailableGroup" value="vehicle.isAvailable">
  <t:label  for="vehicleAvailable" />
  <t:radio t:id="vehicleAvailable" value="literal:true" label="literal:Yes" />
  <t:label for="vehicleNotAvailable" />
  <t:radio t:id="vehicleNotAvailable" value="literal:false" label="literal:No" />
</t:RadioGroup>
```

What's the best way to deal with a create an event or handle an existing event that I may be overlooking?

I've tried add onclick which didn't work, neither did this:

```java
@OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "vehicleAvailableGroup")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Geoff Callender's `zoneUpdater` mixin in JumpStart [here](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/onevent). The mixin listens to a clientside event on a field and fires a serverside event with the current field value.

IMO this should be part of tapestry-core as it's a common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an `observe` mixin which is inspired by jumpstart's `zoneUpdater` mixin. I feel that it is more user friendly than `zoneUpdater` and also more feature rich.

- You can pass a configurable list of clientside fields to the serverside event.
- There's an optional `context` attribute which can be passed in the serverside event which is useful when rendering fields in a `loop`.
- You don't need to mess around with request parameters as field values are passed in the serverside event context.
- You can listen to any clientside element, not just a field. So you can listen for a click on one element and send the value of another field(s).

Demo [here](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/observedemo)